# php script to kill shell 'sleep' process

Tags: php, shell

I need to write some scripts for some automation work,

I put a php file on local apache server
test.php

```
<?php
system("bash inform.sh");
?>
```

the content of inform.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
proc_id=`ps -ef|grep "sleep"|grep -v "grep"|awk '{print $2}'`
kill -9 $proc_id
```

I run sleep process on a shell, and open the php page on firefox :  localhost/test.php
but it doesn't kill the sleep process, 
if I run the php directly through shell, then it works
what's wrong with this and how to deal with it? thanks

Comment: bet a million bucks its a permission issue. the web-server user and what ever you log in to the shell as, have different access

Comment: they are on the same machine

Comment: `$retval = system("bash inform.sh");`  Whats $retval?

Comment: is it possible to change the shell user, like "sudo -u webserver-user sleep"

Comment: regarding the sudo... maybe take a look at `su --session-command=\"bash inform.sh\" someuser &`  But first verify this is permission (user specific) related.  For all I know you are running php 5.16 on a shared host in safe mode.

Comment: what is user1 and & ?  so you mean I put su --session-command=\"bash inform.sh\" user1 & inside php?

Comment: meh, you should have tty so just use `sudo`.

Comment: I have solved this problem, thanks FYI

Answer (score 0):

I use the following shell command and then it is OK:

```
sudo -u apache sleep 2000
```